# Finding out which compiler Maven uses

Tags: maven-2, compiler-construction, java

Do you know how I can find out which of my JDKs Maven uses to compile my projects?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`mvn -version` will spit out the version of maven and the jdk it is using.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you have to be aware of the Maven compiler plugin configuration, cause it could be that there is defined to use a different source/target configuration or may be to use a different JDK etc.

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

could give you the needed information.

Comment: What tags should we be looking at in this file?  (Mine is > 400 lines)

Answer (score 2):

The [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) uses javac by default, and binds by default to the compile lifecycle phase.
This configuration can be overridden see [non-javac compilers](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/non-javac-compilers.html)