# maven is compiling code with java 1.7 but I want it to compile using 1.8

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven and would like to compile my code using JDK 1.8.
So I installed JDK 1.8
Then ( this is on windows ) set the 'path' variable and also 'JAVA_HOME'

> PATH=C:\construction\tools\ibm_sdk80\bin;C:\construction\tools\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin;

the java home:

> C:\Users\satish.marathe>set JAVA_HOME
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\construction\tools\ibm_sdk80

java version give me:

> C:\Users\satish.marathe>java -version
>   java version "1.8.0"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwa6480sr1fp10-20150711_01(SR1 FP10))
>   IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 7 amd64-64 Compressed References 20150630_255633 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
>   J9VM - R28_jvm.28_20150630_1742_B255633
>   JIT  - tr.r14.java_20150625_95081.01
>   GC   - R28_jvm.28_20150630_1742_B255633_CMPRSS
>   J9CL - 20150630_255633)
>   JCL - 20150711_01 based on Oracle jdk8u51-b15

javac version tells me :

> C:\Users\satish.marathe>javac -version
>   javac 1.8.0-internal

So everything seems to point to java 1.8
Now I compile my project using :

```
mvn clean install
```

However when I check the compiled classes I am seeing that the major version is 51 - which means it is Java 1.7
For those who would like to know how the java version is found in a class file ! :)

```
javap -verbose <<your_package>>.<<your_class>> | findStr "major"
```

**EDIT1:**
i forgot to include output of maven -version so here it is:

> C:>mvn -version
>   Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T22:59:23+05:30)
>   Maven home: C:\construction\tools\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin..
>   Java version: 1.8.0, vendor: IBM Corporation
>   Java home: C:\construction\tools\ibm_sdk80\jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
>   OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
>   C:>

OK - so my question is :
I do not have any entry for maven_compiler_plugin in my pom
so is that required ?
without that entry - shouldnt maven simply pick my java version as 1.8 from system and compile the code ( which it does not seem to be doing apparently )
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding out which compiler Maven uses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011977/finding-out-which-compiler-maven-uses)

Comment: i would not look at it as a duplicate - since everything seems to indicate that maven should be using java 1.8 but seems to be using 1.7

Answer (score 6):

You can use `mvn -version` to see which java version is used by Maven.

Your question: I do not have any entry for maven_compiler_plugin in my pom so is that required ?

Answer: If you want a different compiler version to compile your sources then you need to specify that using the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
 <source>1.8</source>
 <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
```

For further information if you look at the maven website: [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html)

> By default The Compiler Plugin is used to compile the sources of your
>   project. Since 3.0, the default compiler is javax.tools.JavaCompiler
>   (if you are using java 1.6) and is used to compile Java sources.

Comment: Thanks - i have included the mvn -version which shows 1.8  and coming to my first question - if I do not include the maven_compiler_plugin which compiler is used by maven - the one that my environment has ? ( which should then be JDK 1.8 right ?)

Answer (score 4):

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
 <source>1.8</source>
 <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks - yes this would compile my code with 1.8 - but I am trying to figure out how and what java version is being used by maven by default ( which should be 1.8 but istnt )

Comment: As per garry answer you can use mvn -version to see which java version is used by Maven.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **maven-compiler-plugin**, replace JAVA_HOME with your local java sdk path.

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <compilerId>javac</compilerId>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <executable>JAVA_HOME/bin/javac</executable>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: thank you I was not aware that you could forcefully set the executable as shown in your example